# Java NIO, what's the ampersand doing in this section of code?

Tags: java, nio, bitwise-operators

I'm reading an article [here](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2007/02/13/architecture-of-highly-scalable-nio-server.html) about building a scale-able java server with Java NIO. It contains the following code snippet:

```
...
while (isRunning) {
  // blocking call, to wait for new readiness events
  int eventCount = selector.select(); 

  // get the events
  Iterator&lt;SelectionKey&gt; it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
  while (it.hasNext()) {
    SelectionKey key = it.next();
    it.remove();

    // readable event?
    if (key.isValid() &amp;&amp; key.isReadable()) {
      eventHandler.onReadableEvent(key.channel());
    }

    // writable event? 
    if (key.isValid() &amp;&amp; key.isWritable()) {
      key.interestOps(SelectionKey.OP_READ); // reset to read only
      eventHandler.onWriteableEvent(key.channel());
    }
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

What is the ampersand doing in the above code? 
Both here:

```
  // get the events
  Iterator&lt;SelectionKey&gt; it = selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
```

and Here:

```
    // readable event?
    if (key.isValid() &amp;&amp; key.isReadable()) {
      eventHandler.onReadableEvent(key.channel());
    }
```

I'm aware a single & is used for bitwise operations in if statements, but I don't understand how it's being applied in the above two examples.

Comment: Looks like escaped HTML - a typo

Comment: God damn it! that thought never occurred to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't compile, since it is escaped HTML entities, `&lt;` is the same as `<` and `&gt;` is the same as `>`

- `lt` stands for less than
- `gt` stands for greater than
- `amp` stands for ampersand

Answer (score 2):

When you copy sources from a website, some special characters aren't converted properly.
In your case the `&lt;` equals `<`, `&gt;` equals `>` and `&amp;`equals `&`